# Sub-Query Should return Null when comparing it to the Next rows from the different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, lead

My T-SQL subquery returning more than 1 rows:

```
WITH ReportView AS
(
    SELECT 
        PMA.AssetName, ReleaseDt, ExpiresDt, TicketNumber, ChangeDt, 
        ChangeReasonCd, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PMA.AssetName, ReleaseDt, ExpiresDt, TicketNumber, ChangeReasonCd 
                           ORDER BY ChangeDt ASC) AS ROW_NUM 
    FROM 
        pmm.pmmreleaserequest PRR WITH (nolock)
    LEFT JOIN 
        pmm.PmmManagedAccount AS PMA WITH (nolock) ON PRR.ManagedAccountID = PMA.ManagedAccountID
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.ManagedEntity AS ME WITH (nolock) ON PRR.ManagedSystemID = ME.ManagedEntityID
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.Asset AS AST WITH (nolock) ON ME.AssetID = AST.AssetID
    LEFT JOIN 
        pmm.PmmLogChange AS PLC WITH (nolock) ON PRR.ManagedAccountID = PLC.ManagedAccountID 
                                              AND PRR.ExpiresDt < PLC.ChangeDt
)
SELECT * 
FROM ReportView 
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

How to compare current row of ChangeDt with the next row of ReleaseDt. Example ChangeDt(current row) < ReleaseDt(Next row)
 How can I put this condition.

Comment: `ROW_NUM` is a **numerical** value - therefore the `WHERE` clause **should be** `WHERE ROW_NUM = 1` - do **NOT** add unnecessary single quotes to numerical values! You're just incurring (totally unnecessary) implicit conversions from a **string value** (`'1'`) back to a numerical value (`1`) ...

Comment: And also: see [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 0):

This is how `row_num` is defined:

```
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PMA.AssetName, ReleaseDt, ExpiresDt, TicketNumber, ChangeReasonCd 
                       ORDER BY ChangeDt ASC) AS ROW_NUM
```

It is going to return one row per unique combination of the columns in the `PARTITION BY`.  That is one row per `PMA.AssetName` / `ReleaseDt` / `ExpiresDt` / `TicketNumber` / `ChangeReasonCd`.

I would expect there to be more than one such combination.

If you want only one row, then use `SELECT TOP (1)` or `OFFSET/FETCH`.

Comment: ChangeDt is having different value. I tried that options it return only one row entirely. Above query does work correctly but extending and trying to add more other condition.

Comment: @tata . . . This addresses the question you asked here, which is why you are getting more than one row.  If you want help with your query, ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you are trying to implement.